# Presencia de "Don" y "Doña" en un padrón mexicano

Tags: historia, nombres-propios

En un padrón mexicano del siglo XVIII, una familia se grabó así. Creo que los cuatro hermanos Fernández fueron hijos de la viúda Margarita Fonseca. Manuel tenía entonces 13 años y de los demás no sé.

> Casa de D.a Margarita Fonseca
>
> D.a Cattharina Fren'z
>
> D.n Joseph Fernandez
>
> Juan Anttonio Fren'z
>
> Manuel Fernandez

¿Porqué dos hijos llevan los títulos Don y Doña y dos otros no? ¿Eso quiere decir que fuesen mayores de edad? (¿Qué edad?)

Answer (score 1):

Según me han dicho el término don o doña es a la persona que ya tiene hijos o bien tiene una edad determinada (mayor que 30) https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_(tratamiento)

https://dle.rae.es/don

Comment: Añade por favor alguna referencia. De lo contrario esto es un comentario y no una respuesta.

Comment: Usuario edito pregunta para agregar referencias, +1

Comment: Fijate que las referencias que citas incluyen una definición más amplia y acabada del sentido de referir a alguien como Don o Doña (completando lo que señalas saber acerca de la edad, ya que se usa como señal de respeto, de consideración en el trato, etc)